# Clicking href links to pdf pages sometimes takes you to the previous link you clicked (Edge)

Tags: html, pdf, href, microsoft-edge

We have a place where there are multiple href links that take you to different page numbers in the same PDF document, like so:

```
href="https://url.website.fake/files/2021-01/documents/a_pdf_file.pdf#page=39"
```

The tester reports that sometimes if they click on link A and then link B, where both links are like the one above but going to different page numbers, the second click will take you to the page number from the previous link.

I've been trying to reproduce but can never do it. The tester is able to reproduce fairly easily. Does this sound like anything anyone here has experienced? Tester has only been able to reproduce this in Edge. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

All browser users are different, so too may be their PDF extension, thus in this case seems they may not have adjusted their Edge viewer use to same as yours. Other browsers have different methods but effect can be the same. You need to educate users to change their browser security.

Check the second setting.
[image]

Most likely theirs is On and yours is Off
its included in how to handle site response such as the download to view.

[image]

Using a simple two page file attempting to swap href ***Sometimes*** (but not always) throws me a warning
[image]

so asking for page 1, I see page 2
[image]

if I switch it off and refresh I will see Page 1
[image]

***For web secure use it is best set On, however for local personal use I tend to switch it Off.*** Most other users would possibly prefer it On to continue at the page where they last read up to.

My MWE which shows above behavior is

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
<a href="http://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#page=2">link A (page 2)</a><p>
<a href="http://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#page=1">link B (Page 1)</a>
</body></html>
```

[link A (page 2)](http://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#page=2)

[link B (Page 1)](http://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#page=1)

Comment: Gah, turns out the tester's settings are same as mine.

Comment: I'll admit I didn't understand that sentence at all, sorry

Comment: I asked another colleague to replicate and she wasn't able to. We decided to table this issue since it's occurring so far only for one person and even then sporadically, and it's something that only a smaller subset of our users can come across anyway, and those users that can most of the time don't actually look at the DPF. Thanks regardless.